# What is the function for moving local files in Symfony?

Tags: php, upload, symfony1, move

Example, move `/var/www/1.jpg` to `/var/www/aaa/1.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

To move a file, you can use [`rename`](http://php.net/rename)

If your file is an uploaded one, you'll want to take a look at [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Here, you'll want to try something like this, I suppose :

```
rename('/var/www/1.jpg', '/var/www/aaa/1.jpg');
```

BTW : those two functions are included in PHP, and not specific to symfony ; maybe there is another special way with symfony... But if you have the required permissions to both files and directories, those should work just fine.